# PC to Mac - Remote Desktop

Tags: software-recommendation, remote-desktop

I want to connect to my mac remotely from my Windows PC. What good products are there available that you recommend checking out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a full list I found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) comparing remote desktop software.

Answer (score 13):

#### [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNC)

Recent versions of Mac OS X include a VNC server built-in, analogous to Microsoft's Remote Desktop Server (included in Windows). This can be accessed via the *System Preferences > Sharing > Apple Remote Desktop* option.

There are various free VNC clients available for Windows, most notably [*RealVNC*](http://www.realvnc.com/index.html).

While there are other options, VNC benefits from being a very mature graphical remote-access protocol with official support from Apple and good-quality client programs.

Comment: I'm enjoying this [ScreenShareMenulet](http://klieme.com/ScreenSharingMenulet.html) program as a quick way to call up machines in my network running VNC or Bonjour desktop sharing.

Comment: Big downside to VNC is not being able to match up screen sizes very well.  Mac desktop won't autosize to your remote screen.  You'll have to try to find a resolution close enough to not be crazy annoying (or live with scaling).

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: That's indeed annoying. Still, good solution in many cases.

Comment: VNC is slow!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I've tried them all and RealVNC is the best by far. Anything else either lacks important functionality or lags miserably. I recommend you try them all though and decide for yourself; it really comes down to what level of remote control you're looking to have.

Answer (score 1):

For quick helpdesk applications I use Teamviewer (https://www.teamviewer.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I *highly* recommend [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/).  It is the fastest remote access program to Mac I've tested.

Comment: Not a big fan of that solution.  Introducing a 3rd party increases the security risks.  If you're in a corporate environment that'll be a huge no-no.

Comment: In a corporate environment support are likely to have a tool to do this (often LogMeIn or Teamviewer)

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using TightVNC to do the same thing.  Lately it has started randomly dropping my connections though.  I can get them back easily enough, but it's very annoying.  Started with the OS X 10.8.1 update so I'm not sure if it's TightVNC or OS X that's got the problem.

Comment: I did more testing and can't recommend TightVNC on current OS X installs due to repeated session drops.  RealVNC works fine, no drops at all.